# Signaling PLC with Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, plc

I want to give signal via PLC to Raspberry Pi and when the raspberry pi gets that signal, it should run the python script and when the python script execute properly and cycle is completed, it should wait for the other signal from PLC to again run the same script and same cycle should go on.

Please provide some suggestions.

Comment: What PLC brand?

Comment: programmable logic controller

Comment: Yes but what brand... Siemens, Omron, Beckhoff...

Comment: @quirzo Siemens

Answer (score 1):

**Via Network:**

Depending on your PLC, you could use UDP or TCP, where a Python program on Raspberry listens and sends commands. Depending on the command received, different scripts ou actions could be executed. There are many Python examples for using this on the internet.

For the PLC it can be a little more complicated to find and it will depend on the model and manufacturer, I recommend that you check your supplier's documentation.

**Discrete Inputs:**

I don't recommend it, but if it's impossible to use a network, you could use discrete digital inputs (like buttons do) to trigger the scripts on the Raspberry, but it must have an interface with relays or optocouplers between the PLC and the Raspberry due to differences in types of electrical signals. In this mode, scripty in pyton keeps checking the status of a digital input and triggers the action when the status of the input changes.

**Note:**

- Note that in both cases the program remains running (in an infinite loop), waiting for the command.
- Additional care must be taken when using the Raspberry in an industrial environment due to possible interference by EMC. If using digital inputs, consider applying filters to the signal and shilded cables.

Comment: I2C or SPI would also be an option